# Problema al convertir codigo Java a PHP

Tags: php, java

Como están estimados, tengo el siguiente codigo en Java, que me calcula el digito modulo 11 a partir de una cadena, pasando algunos parametros de referencia (fragmento de codigo de un proveedor para implementar calculos  https://siatinfo.impuestos.gob.bo/index.php/facturacion-en-linea/algoritmos-utilizados/algoritmo-modulo-11):

```
public String calculaDigitoMod11(String cadena, int numDig, int limMult, boolean x10)
{
    int mult, suma, i, n, dig; 
      if (!x10) numDig = 1;
      for(n = 1; n <= numDig; n++) {
        suma = 0;
        mult = 2;
        for(i = cadena.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           suma += (mult * Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(i, i + 1)));
           if(++mult > limMult) mult = 2;
        }
        if (x10) {
           dig = ((suma * 10) % 11) % 10;
        }
         else {
           dig = suma % 11;
         }                   
             if (dig == 10) {
                    cadena += "1";
             }
             if (dig == 11) {
                    cadena += "0";
             }
             if (dig < 10) {
                    cadena += String.valueOf(dig);
             }     
       }
       return cadena.substring(cadena.length() - numDig, cadena.length());
}
```

Ejemplo de consumo del método:

```
    public String obtenerModulo11(String pCadena) {
    
    String vDigito = calculaDigitoMod11(pCadena, 1, 9, false);    
           return vDigito;

}
```

Y pues yo  intenté pasar este fragmento, a codigo PHP, pero los valores que me devuelve no son los que espero:

```
class Test
{
    public static function test(){
        //valores de entrada son cadena, numdig, limult y x10 segun la documentacion, el resultado final debe ser 1
        $cadena="00001234567892019011316372123100001110100000000010000";
        $numDig=1;
        $limMult=9;
        $x10=false;
        if(!$x10){
            $numDig=1;
        }
        for($n=1;$n<=1;$n++){
            $suma=0;
            $mult=2;
            for($i=(strlen($cadena)-1);$i>=0;$i--){
                $suma= $suma+ ($mult* intval(substr($cadena,$i,$i+1)) );
                if(++$mult>$limMult){
                    $mult=2;
                }
            }
        }
        if($x10){
            $dig=(($suma * 10) % 11) % 10;
        }else{
            $dig=$suma%11;
        }
        if($dig == 10){
            $cadena+="1";
        }
        if($dig == 11){
            $cadena+="0";
        }
        if($dig<10){
            $cadena+="$dig";
        }
        return substr($cadena, strlen($cadena)-$numDig,strlen($cadena)  );
    }
    
}

print_r(Test::test());
```

El resultado final son completamente distintos, el codigo java considerando la entrada de parametros, debe ser 1 (y si, me retorna 1 que es el valor correcto), pero en php me retorna 9.

Parametros de entrada:

```
cadena="00001234567892019011316372123100001110100000000010000"
numDig="1"
limMult=9
x10=false
```

Comment: alguna idea por que no devuelve lo que esperas??? falla todo o algo en especifico??

Comment: creo que es por el parseo de tipos de datos...

Comment: bueno si explicas que es lo que debe de hacer la clase a lo mejor te decimos si hay algun error logico...

Comment: Creo que tu problema está aquí: `Integer.parseInt(cadena.substring(i, i + 1)`. ¿Podrías verbalizar lo que hace esa parte de tu código en Java?

Comment: Está rara (medio inútil) esa validación `if(++$mult>$limMult){` porque nunca vuelven a usar `mult` (en ambos códigos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código tiene **tres problemas**.

Aquí:

```
$suma= $suma+ ($mult* intval(substr($cadena,$i,$i+1)) );
```

Y en este bloque:

```
    if($dig == 10){
        $cadena+="1";
    }
    if($dig == 11){
        $cadena+="0";
    }
    if($dig<10){
        $cadena+="$dig";
    }
```

Y en el `return`:

```
    return substr($cadena, strlen($cadena)-$numDig,strlen($cadena)  );
```

El **primer problema** puedes resolverlo accediendo al carácter deseado por su posición en la cadena, así simplemente:

```
$suma+=  ($mult*intval($cadena[$i]));
```

En PHP una cadena es considerada un array de caracteres.

En cuanto al **segundo problema**, recuerda que para concatenar cadenas en PHP debes usar `.=`, si usas `+` podrías estar forzando una operación aritmética.

En cuanto al **tercer problema**, puedes retornar también el carácter buscando su posición, por lo dicho más arriba (una cadena es un array de caracteres).

El `return` por tanto puede quedar así simplemente:

```
return $cadena[strlen($cadena)-$numDig];
```

He aquí un código completo, mejorando también otras cosas:

[Ver DEMO en Rextester](https://rextester.com/GSPWJ49339)

```
<?php

class Test
{
    public static function testA(){
        //valores de entrada son cadena, numdig, limult y x10 segun la documentacion, el resultado final debe ser 1
        $cadena="00001234567892019011316372123100001110100000000010000";
        $numDig=1;
        $limMult=9;
        $x10=false;
        if(!$x10){
            $numDig=1;
        }
        for($n=1;$n<=1;$n++){
            $suma=0;
            $mult=2;
            $strLen=strlen($cadena);
            for($i=($strLen-1);$i>=0;$i--){
                $suma+=  ($mult*intval($cadena[$i]));
                if(++$mult>$limMult){
                    $mult=2;
                }
            }
        }
        if($x10){
            $dig=(($suma * 10) % 11) % 10;
        }else{
            $dig=$suma%11;
        }
        if($dig == 10){
            $cadena.="1";
        }
        if($dig == 11){
            $cadena.="0";
        }
        if($dig<10){
            $cadena.="$dig";
        }
        return $cadena[strlen($cadena)-$numDig];
    }
    
}

print_r(Test::testA());
    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema parecería estar en la línea

```
$suma= $suma+ ($mult* intval(substr($cadena,$i,$i+1)) );
```

Porque haces `substr($cadena,$i,$i+1)` y ahí es una mala traducción del código Java, entendiendo que quieres la subcadena desde la posición `i` hasta la posición `i+1`.

Allá en Java, [`substring(start, end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) pide como parámetros las posiciones inicial y final. En PHP, [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) pide como parámetros la cadena, la posición inicial (el offset) **y la longitud de la subcadena**. Entendería que esa en tu caso siempre debe ser 1.

```
$suma= $suma+ ($mult* intval(substr($cadena, $i, 1)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias estimados, si, problemas por aqui y por allá! xD, lo resolvi leyendo acerca de la operacion de M11, aqui el codigo corregido:

```
class Test
{
    public static function test2(){
        $cadena="00001234567892019011316372123100001110100000000010000";
        $acumulador=0;
        $factor=2;
        while($cadena!=""){
            $dig=intval($cadena[strlen($cadena)-1]);
            $acumulador=$acumulador+($dig*$factor);
            if($factor==7){
                $factor=2;
            }else{
                $factor++;
            }
            $cadena=substr($cadena,0,strlen($cadena)-1);
        }
        $m11=$acumulador%11;
        $res=11-$m11;
        if($res==11){
            $res=0;
        }else if($res==10){
            $res=1;
        }
        return $res;
    }
    
    
}

print_r(Test::test2());
```